# jQuery: Match a list with less than X items

Tags: jquery

I want add a class to lists, but only if they have 3 or less items:

```
var ol = $('ol');
var len = ol.children('li').length;

//0 based?
while(len < 2) {

    $("ol").addClass("small-list");

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hryZ4/2/

How would I add such a conditional clause?

All I found was something mroe or less unrelated: [Fill list up to 10 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179799/fill-list-up-to-10-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will check and fixup every `<ol>` on your page:

```
$('ol').filter(function() {
   return ($(this).children('li').length <= 3);
}).addClass('small-list');
```

i.e. for every `<ol`> which satisfies the supplied function, add the required class.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/9uTvT/

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't get the "valid HTML" version working. Would like to use the most efficient version of course :) http://jsfiddle.net/9uTvT/6/

Comment: yes - my mistake.  I forgot that `element.childNodes` includes text elements, including whitespace.  Whereas jQuery's `$(element).children()` only includes tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ol = $("ol");
ol.each(function() {
    if ($(">li", this).length <= 3) {
        $(this).addClass("small-list");
    }
});
```

I think you can try this :)

Comment: Your condition should be <=3 according to description. His code that you based that on is wrong. ;-)

Comment: You should be able to edit your own post to update this I think (I believe you can edit your own post no matter the rep). If not then let me know and I'll edit your answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function to addClass() since jQuery 1.4

```
$('ol').addClass(function(){
    var retClass;
    if (this.children.length<=3){
        retClass='small-list';}
    return retClass;
});
```

Comment: list elements don't have a `length` property

Comment: didn't pay attention to the detail. changed it to children